# Table width 100%. 1 column fixed width

Tags: css

here is the code i'm having a problem with:

http://jsfiddle.net/crptS/

Basically I have a table, and the width of the table is 100%

```
table
{
 border: 1px solid #ffda95;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
```

now I have 1 column which contains 3 icons and I dont want this column to scale with the page. it should have a width of 25px. the `td` has the class `tdmaxwidth60`

```
.tdmaxwidth60
{
    width: 25px;
    min-width: 25px;
    max-width: 25px;
}
```

however. in Firefox and IE this column still scales with the page, be it slightly different than in jsFiddle. it looks like the `width` is working (on load width is correct) and the `min-width` too works, when you have the page fullscreen and you make it smaller it stays the same width. however when you load the page on a small page and then make it fullscreen the width of the column does stretch.

any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the jsfiddle you posted 4 columns have fixed widths. Therefor they all scales to suit that width of the table.

If you only set the width of the first column then the other columns will scale to fit. And the first column will stay the same.

Comment: yeah i just found out datatables.net puts fixed widths on the `th` elements. if i can disable that it'll be fixed

Comment: Do you use jQuery datatables? (the best table library of them all?)

Answer (score 0):

When you're saying you've got a column you do not want to scale, shouldn't you give your `trmaxwidth60` class to every td within that column instead of the tr? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: yeah i'm sorry i DID do it on the TD, i just was wrong in my question :)

Answer (score -2):

you can use `white-space: nowrap;` for the `.trmaxwidth60`. Of course the default use is for text, but I think will do the job for the icons also.